# Data Science - Model Recommendation

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science, anomaly-detection

Could anyone please help me with recommending a strategy to detect the rule breakers from a Data Set.

For Example:

If i have a dataset with 4 columns - [CustomerName,CardType,BankName,Country]

So as DataSet Rule : Each Customer should have only one Card from One Bank within one Country.

**Ideal** **Dataset** :

```
**CustomerName - CardType - BankName - Country**

1)        Tony - VISA - CITI - USA
```

**How to detect the Rule Breakers ?**

```
**CustomerName - CardType - BankName - Country**

1)        Tony - VISA - CITI - USA

2)        Anthony - VISA - BOFA - USA

3)        Anthony - MC - BOFA - USA

4)        Anthony - VISA - CITI - USA

5)        Anthony - MC - BOFA - USA

6)        Jess - VISA - AMEX - USA

7)        Jess - VISA - BOFA - USA

8)        Jess - VISA - AMEX - USA
```

**Desired output to detect the Rule Breaker** i.e., One Customer either having more than one CardType or one Bank from one Country considering the column CustomerName as primary key and first recorded values(Cardtype,Bank,Country)of that particular CustomerName as True.

Example Output:

```
**CustomerName - CardType - BankName - Country**


3)        Anthony - MC - BOFA - USA

4)        Anthony - VISA - CITI - USA

5)        Anthony - MC - BOFA - USA

7)        Jess - VISA - BOFA - USA
```

Thanks in advance,

Note: I've done analysis using pandas by grouping Primary Key with individual column, i.e, grouping CustomerName and any other column to get the rule breakers with count more than 1.
But is there any way to detect these Rule Breakers rather than analyzing them individually?

I've 18 different columns to detect so it would be really helpful to recommend/enlighten me with model/algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['column_names',..])`
check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). This might help you.

Comment: If we use drop_duplicates then we also get records which are valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is going to help you. But can you use any Global dictionary to store a value for each row?

For example, you have this rule "So as DataSet Rule: Each Customer should have only one Card from One Bank within one Country" and consider this row "Tony - VISA - CITI - USA". Create a string "TonyCITIUSA" by concatenating all the values of the column for that row required for the rule.

`s = "TonyCITIUSA"
globalDict = {}`

Now check if the string is present in the Global dictionary and if it's present that means the row is a rule breaker if there is no string present in the dictionary. Then add the string to the dictionary for future use.

`if s in globalDict:
       //Rule breaker found
   else:
      globalDict.add(s)`

Please let me if this works!

Comment: I don’t think it’s to going help because if we concat all the string values “TonyBOFAUSA” will be taken as new value and it will store in the dictionary but it’s a rule breaker since TONY cannot have two accounts as dataset rule. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Oh, I probably understood the question in a wrong manner. Will update with any other solution if I get one.